# Skip first rows from CSV with Python without reading the file

Tags: python, csv

I need to skip some first lines from a CSV file and save it to another file.

The code i currently accomplish such tasks is:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('users.csv', skiprows=2)    
df.to_csv("usersOutput.csv", index=False)
```

and it works without issues. The only thing is: this code reads the whole file before saving. Now my problem is: i have to deal with a file with 4GB size and i think, this code will be very time consuming.

Is there a possibility to skip some first lines and save the file without to read it before?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to use `pandas` just to filter lines from a file:

```
with open('users.csv') as users, open('usersOutput.csv', 'w') as output:
    for lineno, line in enumerate(users):
        if lineno > 1:
            output.write(line)
```

Answer (score 2):

The most efficient way with [`shutil.copyfileobj(fsrc, fdst[, length])`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html#shutil.copyfileobj) feature:

```
from shutil import copyfileobj
from itertools import islice

with open('users.csv') as f_old, open('usersOutput.csv', 'w') as f_new:
    list(islice(f, 2))   # skip 2 lines
    copyfileobj(f_old, f_new)
```

---

From *doc*:

> ... if the current file position of the `fsrc` object is not `0`, only
>   the contents from the current file position to the end of the file
>   will be copied.

i.e. the new file will contain the same content except the first 2 lines.

Comment: this solution is fast too, but not handy - one should add as much times `next(f_old)`, as much lines one wants to skip.

Comment: @Evgeniy, and that's absolutely wrong conclusion. See my update. (with `f_old.readlines(<number>)` you can skip as much lines as needed). I've used `next` because your case was quite simple

Comment: This is a great answer, very efficient.

Comment: @PeterWood, Thanks, I'm glad that there's people that realize what way is really faster and efficient.